# If de-referencing a NULL pointer is an invalid thing to do, how should auto pointers be implemented?

Tags: c++

I thought dereferencing a NULL pointer was dangerous, if so then what about this implementation of an auto_ptr?

http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html

If the default constructor is invoked without a parameter the internal pointer will be NULL, then when operator*() is invoked won't that be dereferencing a null pointer?

Therefore what is the industrial strength implementation of this function?

Comment: This is like asking what the industrial strength implementation of `*` is, because the "obvious" implementation blows up when you apply it to a null pointer.

Comment: FWIW, [`boost::scoped_ptr<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm)  has been adopted by C++0x as `std::scoped_ptr<>`.  There are good reasons for preferring it over the standard `auto_ptr<>`.

Comment: @ephemient: 1. It's `std::unique_ptr`. 2. Some of us don't have C++0x support. It's kind of unreasonable to be complaining about using the best tools available in the current standard.

Comment: Oops, they renamed it.  What I really mean, though, is that you can use `boost::scoped_ptr<>` regardless of whether you're on C++03 or C++0x.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: with the current Standard **absolutely anything** including nuking the C++ committee is better than auto_ptr. Don't touch it. There's a long history here which makes the "tree-swing" cartoons look tame.

Comment: @Yttrill: Sorry, but I STRONGLY disagree.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, dereferencing NULL pointer = bad.

Yes, constructing an auto_ptr with NULL creates a NULL auto_ptr.

Yes, dereferencing a NULL auto_ptr = bad.

*Therefore what is the industrial strength implementation of this function?*

I don't understand the question.  If the definition of the function in question created by the industry itself is not "industrial strength" then I have a very hard time figuring out what might be.

Answer (score 2):

`std::auto_ptr` is intended to provide essentially the same performance as a "raw" pointer. To that end, it doesn't (necessarily) do any run-time checking that the pointer is valid before being dereferenced.

If you want a pointer that checks validity, it's relatively easy to provide that, but it's not the intended purpose of `auto_ptr`. In fairness, I should add that the real intent of `auto_ptr` is rather an interesting question -- its specification was changed several times during the original standardization process, largely because of disagreements over what it should try to accomplish. The version that made it into the standard does have some uses, but quite frankly, not very many. In particular, it has transfer-of-ownership semantics that make it unsuitable for storage in a standard container (among other things), removing one of the obvious purposes for smart pointers in general.

Answer (score 1):

Its purpose to *help* prevent memory leaks by ensuring that `delete` is performed on the underlying pointer whenever the `auto_ptr` goes out of scope (or itself is `delete`d).

Just like in higher-level languages such as C#, trying to dereference a `null` pointer/object will still explode, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Do what you would do if you dereferenced a NULL pointer.  On many platforms, this means throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just like you said: dereferencing null pointer is illegal, leads to undefined behavior. This immediately means that you must not use operator `*` on a default-constructed `auto_ptr`. Period.

Where exactly you see a problem with "industrial strength" of this implementation is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

@Jerry Coffin: It is naughty of me to answer your answer here rather than the OP's question but I need more lines than a comment allows..

You are completely right about the ridiculous semantics of the current version, it is so completely rotten that a new feature: "mutable" HAD to be added to the language just to allow these insane semantics to be implemented.

The original purpose of "auto_ptr" was exactly what boost::scoped_ptr does (AFAIK), and I'm happy to see a version of that finally made it into the new Standard. The reason for the name "auto_ptr" is that it should model a first class pointer on the stack, i.e. an automatic variable.

This auto_ptr was an National Body requirement, based on the following logic: if we have catchable exceptions in C++, we MUST have a way to manage pointers which is exception safe IN the Standard. This also applies to non-static class members (although that's a slightly harder problem which required a change to the syntax and semantics of constructors).

In addition a reference counting pointer was required but due to a lot of different possible implementation with different tradeoffs, one can accept that this be left out of the Standard until a later time.

Have you ever played that game where you pass a message around a ring of people and at the end someone reads out the input and output messages? That's what happened. The original intent got lost because some people thought that the auto_ptr, now we HAD to have it, could be made to do more... and finally what got put in the standard can't even do what the original simple scope_ptr style one did (auto_ptr semantics don't assure the pointed at object is destroyed because it could be moved elsewhere).

If I recall the key problem was returning the value of a auto_ptr: the core design simply doesn't allow that (it's uncopyable). A sane solution like

```
return ap.swap(NULL)
```

unfortunately still destroys the intended invariant. The right way is probably closer to:

```
return ap.clone();
```

which copies the object and returns the copy, destroying the original: the compiler is then free to optimise away the copy (as written not exception safe .. the clone might leak if another exception is thrown before it returns: a ref counted pointer solves this of course).